# Correlation Analysis

Tags: correlation, pearson

I want to try and compare data on employee performance to an engagement survey.  If I have employees who are ranked 1-5 for certain performance categories, can I correlate this with engagement scores?  I am using Pearson Correlation, is that allowed.  I also want to show a linear regression.
example
employee 1:
good leader  5 (rating can be 1-5)
listens to other  3 (rating can be 1-5)
communication  2 (rating can be 1-5)
manages work  1 (rating can be 1-5)
values opinion  3 (rating can be 1-5)

I want to take each of those performance rating categories and correlate it to an engagement score.  So, employee 1 scored 75% on engagement. Can i correlate engagement score with good leader score using pearson correlation.

I would use the performance rating and engagement scores of many different employees to see if someone is a good leader scores high on engagement.